# How to add godaddy's SSL certificate to goolge cloud storage hosted static website with godaddy domain

Tags: google-cloud-storage, ssl-certificate

I have a static website hosted on google cloud storage and I also bought godaddy's domain. Now my website is working fine with domain but it is not secured so I bought godaddy's SSL certificate. How to add SSL certificate to Google Cloud Storage static website?

I have tried to find multiple solutions but they are using CLoudFare or it involves google App Engine but as my website is hosted on google cloud storage and I already bought SSL certificate so I need solutions using this SSL certificate and GCS.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your google cloud storage to Google Cloud LoadBalancer. The steps are really easy as mentioned here:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets

You also can skip GoDaddy SSL certificate and let Google manage SSL certificate for you free of cost. As mentioned here:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs